# EcmaScript syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

Question related to EcmaScript:

```
const firstArg = 'myArg';
this._myFunction(firstArg)
  .then((asyncResponse) => this._secondMethod(asyncResponse))
  .then((asyncSecondResponse, asyncResponse) => 
   this._thirdMethod(asyncSecondResponse, asyncResponse))
  .then(() => this._lastMethod());
```

The problem is:
How to pass to the  to the `_thirdMethod` 2 arguments (one from `this._secondMethod(asyncResponse))` - that gives one argument and second is just previous `asyncResponse`) - I don’t want to define it inside _secondMethod(asyncResponse) to return these two arguments, just want to do it in this PIPE that I wrote above

Is there any syntax for it?

Comment: Please have a look at the async waterfall.
https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall

Comment: Do you want to use the responses for each subsequent call?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with nesting them here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also nest the second "then" to keep the first asyncResponse in the scope

```
this._myFunction(firstArg)
    .then((asyncResponse) => this._secondMethod(asyncResponse)
    .then((asyncSecondResponse) => this._thirdMethod(asyncSecondResponse, asyncResponse)))
    .then(() => this._lastMethod());
  }
```